# Macro command button to add a row below a clicked row and copy its only formula to a new row

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a time sheet where user can click on the + command button, it will add a new row below the clicked command button row and copy the formula to the new row. Users need to enter their hour worked for different funding sources on the same day on several rows.

The macro below works fine however, it adds a row **ABOVE** the clicked row instead of **BELOW** the clicked row. I am posting this question with hope that some experts from this forum can help me.  Thank you very much in advance.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim row As Long

    'Insert new row on button row
    row = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.row
    Rows(row).Insert

    'AutoFill from 1 row above new row for 1 row down
    Rows(row - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Rows(row - 1 & ":" & row), Type:=xlFillDefault

    'Clear cells A-S on new row
    Range("A" & row & ":F" & row).ClearContents
    Range("H" & row & ":P" & row).ClearContents


End Sub
```

Comment: `Rows(row + 1).Insert`

Comment: Thank you very much Davis.  It works.  Here is my complete macro.         Sub Macro1()
    Dim row As Long
    
    'Insert new row below button row
    row = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.row
    Rows(row + 1).Insert
    
    'AutoFill new row down
    Rows(row).AutoFill Destination:=Rows(row + 1 & ":" & row), Type:=xlFillDefault
    
    'Clear cells A:F and H:M on new row
    Range("A" & row + 1 & ":F" & row + 1).ClearContents
    Range("H" & row + 1 & ":M" & row + 1).ClearContents
    
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Davis. It works. Here is my complete macro.

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim row As Long

    'Insert new row on button row
    row = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.row
    Rows(row + 1).Insert

    'AutoFill new row
    Rows(row).AutoFill Destination:=Rows(row + 1 & ":" & row), Type:=xlFillDefault

    'Clear cells A:F and H:M on new row
    Range("A" & row + 1 & ":F" & row + 1).ClearContents
    Range("H" & row + 1 & ":M" & row + 1).ClearContents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code.

```
Sub CopyRow_Only_Formulas()
'              Select current Row and Copy paste it to the next row
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
'             Save the new row as Reference
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.End(xlToLeft).Select
Dim myC As Range
Set myC = ActiveCell
'             Determine how many columns based on Row1/A1
Dim x As Integer
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
x = Selection.Columns.Count
'             x = Columns.Count is not used because it returns too much column count
'             Return back to the New Row Reference again and select it
myC.Select
Dim i As Integer
'             loop thru the cells of the row
For i = 1 To x - 1
    '             ActiveCell.HasFormula = True
    If ActiveCell.HasFormula = False Then
        Selection.ClearContents
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).